# LinkedIn Authentication using OAuth2: success but no session in LinkedIn site

Tags: linkedin-api

I have code to login to my website using LinkedIn Oauth 2.

I'm using RESTFUL API.

Referred this: https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2

I followed the instruction and got access token from LinkedIn, I can use token to retrieve data.

Back to LinkedIn.com, I was asked to input credentials to login. I assume that after authenticating using OAuth2, I can use my account in LinkedIn.com without additional authentication steps.

I tried to sign in using Javascript SDK. It works fine, I can authenticate from my site, and also on Linkedin site, as my expectation. (and looks like this method uses OAuth1)

Am I doing smthing wrong with OAuth2?

Comment: could you please provide a sample code how you did authentication from client side using javascript ?  I tried by myself but not able to accomplish. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Successfully authenticating via a 3rd-party application using OAuth 2.0 will not have any affect at all on your login state with the www.linkedin.com website - so the behaviour you are experiencing is expected.

When you use the JavaScript SDK to authenticate, it is using the website's authentication process behind the scenes and setting the necessary browser cookies to allow you to be logged into www.linkedin.com as well - also, expected behaviour ... and different from the way a server-side OAuth 2.0 authentication occurs.